# UNIX: using tr to delete empty lines

Tags: linux, unix, sed, tr

I've seen it being done using sed (if you'd be so kind to write how to do it in sed and explain the regex behind it, I will appreciate it too), but I'd like to know how to do it using tr.

My idea was: `cat file|tr -d ^'\n'` or `^\n`, but the first one deleted every '\n', the second one none.

Comment: Your (first) command should delete all newlines AND `^` characters.  The fragment you have after the 'or' should give a shell error about the mismatched `'`

Comment: @stark's answer is correct, but you accepted one that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @KeithThompson stark's answer doesn't entirely work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70613222/unix-using-tr-to-delete-empty-lines/70615931#comment124831978_70613469.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tr on linux, at least, can squeeze repeated characters:

```
echo -ne $a
the quick
brown fox

jumps over
echo -ne $a |tr -s '\n'
the quick
brown fox
jumps over
```

Comment: This isn't specific to Linux. The `-s` option is specified by POSIX. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html

Comment: That wouldn't delete a blank line at the start of the input. Try `printf '\na\n' | tr -s '\n'`.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is `grep . file`.

Answer (score 1):

tr operates on streams of characters, not streams of lines (which is the default for sed and awk and whatnot).  The -d flag deletes any of the characters in the character list.  `tr -d '\n'` will delete all the newlines in the stream.

I'm not sure myself if you can delete empty lines using tr.

To use sed `sed '/^$/d'`.  `^` matches front of line.  `$` matches end of line `d` says you want sed to delete anything that matches that.  However, this type of question has been answered much more comprehensively elsewhere so I'd go back to google and find a comprehensive sed or unix tutorial.

Comment: The other answer is correct; `tr -s '\n'` will delete blank lines.

Comment: Not sure why this is voted down, as OP asked for a sed solution, also.

Comment: @KeithThompson not if a newline is at the beginning or end of the file.

Comment: @stark Good point. I tried to withdraw my downvote, but I can't unless the answer is edited.

Answer (score 0):

`tr` is short for **tr**anslate. It's to convert one set of characters to another. That has nothing to do with deleting blank lines from a file, there's several other tools you can do that with (e.g. sed, awk, grep).

The simple ways to delete empty lines using mandatory POSIX tools are:

```
grep '.' file
grep -v '^$' file

sed -n '/./p' file
sed '/^$/d' file

awk '/./' file
awk '!/^$/' file
awk '$0 != ""' file
awk 'length($0) != 0' file
```